# Can I use interior fasteners for exterior brick mold if I seal the holes?

Tags: exterior, trim, fastener

I am installing simple exterior door trim with Azec (actually Versatex but it's the same thing) lumber. Some of it will be screwed and nailed into an existing frame nested in masonry, and some into the brick itself.

Considering that I don't want the fasteners to be visible, I plan to use either trim screws or deeply set 1"  brad nails for a few pieces that require thinner (1/2" as opposed to 3/4") board. My question is, can I use regular indoor fasteners if I seal their holes with some kind of speckle (maybe door trim caulking or some exterior equivalent of wood putty) so that they are protected from moisture/corrosion? Or should I look for exterior rated fasteners?

Comment: Won't such fasteners be exposed to moisture _behind_ the brick mold?

Comment: @isherwood I'm hoping to seal it (with caulking etc)

Comment: I guess this is a subjective question. If you want it to last, do it right. You can get galvanized trim gun nails.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you can keep the bricks, and the mold, and the cracks dry you'll be fine.

This is probably not the case, so get galvanised or stainless fasteners.